# SQL for rows created in a week of eachother

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table that logs every time a person presses a button.
Using postgres

So I have alot of data like this:

```
PressedButton
__________
ID || userId || timestamp
__________
```

How can I select the count of the users doing this at least once a week?

Comment: I use postgres, but if you can do it in any DBMS with an SQL query I would probably be able to make it from there. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (all as formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

"Once a week"

By default doing it once already is done once a week. Do you mean every week without skips?

Or just has pressed the button in the last 7 days?
That would be:

```
Select *
From table
Where timestamp>=adddate(now(),-7)
```

**EDIT**

This isn't exactly what you want, but it will show all users who have done it at least 2 time

```
SELECT ID, distinct(userId),timestamp
FROM table
Group by userId
Having COUNT(ID) => 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But im looking more for the recurring. Atleast 2 weeks in a row.

Comment: Posted an edit, to give you a direction you must think of.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want, but to get the number of button presses per user and week, you can use something like this:

```
select userid, to_char(timestamp, 'iyyy-iw') as week, count(*)
from pressedbutton
group by userid, to_char(timestamp, 'iyyy-iw')
having count(*) > 1 --<< at least once a week
```

`to_char(timestamp, 'iyyy-iw')` returns the timestamp formatted as the ISO year/ISO week combination and the count(*) then counts how many times the user pressed a button in that week.